# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from (PHP 5.6 Certificate checking)

Tags: php, ssl, soap, wsdl

I have been fighting the following error for longer than I would like to admit. The solutions I was finding were not related to what the actual problem was.

PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://x.x.x.x/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi?WSDL=LocalLB.Class' : failed to load external entity "https://x.x.x.x/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi?WSDL=LocalLB.Class"

My prod environment is CentOS 6 which is packaged with PHP 5.3 which has been EOL since August 2014. From my understanding CentOS backports security fixes, I still wanted to do some testing with a newer version and there was some other features not available in 5.3 that I could possibly leverage.

I built out a new DEV environment with PHP 5.6 and all seemed to be working until I tried a SOAP call and got the message above. After a lot of searching I finally found that in PHP 5.6 SSL Certificate check is enabled by default. In my DEV environment it is completely contained and the application requires SSL. I do not have a valid certificate. I have not tested in my PROD environment which does have valid certificates.

To get around this I added:

```
'stream_context'=>stream_context_create
(
    array
    (
        'ssl'=>array
        (
            'verify_peer'=>false, 
            'verify_peer_name'=>false
        )
    )
)
```

Here it is put together in the code. This is kind of messy just threw it together for testing.

```
<?php

$device_ip = "x.x.x.x";
$user = "username";
$pw = "password";

$location = "https://" . $device_ip . "/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi?";
$wsdl_class = "https://" . $device_ip . "/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi?WSDL=LocalLB.Class";
$soap_class = new SoapClient($wsdl_class, array('location'=>$location, 'login'=>$user, 'password'=>$pw, 'stream_context'=>stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array('verify_peer'=>false, 'verify_peer_name'=>false)))));

$response = $soap_class->get_string_class(array("SomeName"));
var_dump($response);

?>
```

although I was able to find a workaround for not having a valid certificate. Is there a way to import the self-signed certificate so that I would not have use the workaround in my DEV environment?

Comment: I notice you are working with iControl. Worth noting is that iControl now supports the [REST api](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/introducing-a-restful-interface-for-icontrol) which is much simpler to use than WSDL/XML. You may wish to give this a try instead.

Comment: I have been doing some testing with the REST api and will be looking at migrating my code hopefully in the near future. I agree though much simpler to work with.